# Leer txt de abajo hacia arriba

Tags: php

Tengo este simple código que lee un archvo; notas.txt.  Los ultimos datos los deja abajo y no arriba, eso es normal por como se guardan, pero como puedo hacer para que se lean de abajo hacia arriba.

```
<?php
$ar = fopen("notas.txt","r") or die("NULL");
while (!feof($ar)){
  $linea = fgets($ar);
  $lineasalto = nl2br($linea);
  echo $lineasalto;
}
fclose($ar);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes leer todas las líneas del fichero y guardarlas en un array con

```
$lineas = file("notas.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Luego puedes invertir el array con `array_reverse` o bien puedes recorrerlo en un bucle for desde la última posición hasta el inicio.

```
<?php
$lineas = file("notas.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$numElementos = count($lineas) - 1;

for ($i = $numElementos; $i >= 0; $i--) {
   echo nl2br($lineas[$i]);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo probe y solo me queda cambiar el orden de como se guarda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el comando `tac` o guardar los elementos previamente en un array y usar `reverse order` para recorrerlos de forma inversa

```
$myfile = 'myfile.txt';
$command = "tac $myfile > /tmp/myfilereversed.txt";
```

http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-reverse.php

Comment: Gracias Rafael, no sabia del comando `tac`, voy a leer, quizas me sirva para futuros proyectos.